# Entire function and odd/even function

Tags: complex-analysis

f is an entire function.If $$f(R)\subset R,f(iR)\subset iR,$$then f(z) is an odd function;Similarly,if$$f(R)\subset R,f(iR)\subset R,$$then f is an even function.

Answer (score 4):

Recall the Schwarz reflection principal: if $g$ is any entire function that maps $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, then $g(\overline{z}) = \overline{g(z)}$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$.

For the first case, it follows that $g(z) + g(-z) = 0$ on the imaginary axis. It must be zero everywhere, then, because zeros of (nonzero) analytic functions are isolated, and so $g$ is odd. The second case is analogous.